# Azure APIM as pure proxy

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to deal with an Backend API(REST) with no swagger documents to be accessed through Azure APIM. 
I want all the calls directed to the Backend API with me not manually creating GET/PUT/POST for all the resources. My inbound policies for all operations is below
'

```html
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <set-variable name="requestPath" value="@(context.Request.Url.Path)" />
    <base/>
    <set-backend-service base-url="https://*****/****/" />
    <rewrite-uri template="@(context.Request.Url.Path)" copy-unmatched-params="true" />
  </inbound>
  <backend>
    <base/>
  </backend>
  <outbound>
    <base/>
  </outbound>
</policies>
```

`
However when hit the APIM i was given

`{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "Resource not found"
}`
Any help is appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to create one operation for each HTTP method you support and use `/*` for the template.  This will match any inbound path/query and forward it to the backend.